# Как получить java object в thymeleaf через authentication

Tags: java, spring-security, thymeleaf

Я могу получить имя текущего пользователя `<span sec:authentication="name">UserName</span>`, а как получить полноценный объект что бы дергать у него любые поля?

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно в контроллере передать обьект.

```
User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

И обьект будет полный если класс Юзер имплиментирует интерфейс UserDetails.

Comment: Как я могу из thymeleaf обратиться к controller?